# Building MongoDB 3.5.13 source on Fedora

Tags: mongodb, gcc, g++, fedora

I am trying to build **MongoDB 3.5.13** from source on **Fedora 27** using GCC and G++ **5.3.0** and **SCons 3.0.1** with the following command:

`scons MONGO_VERSION=3.5.13 -j16 CC=gcc53 CXX=g++53 mongod`

And I have been unable to build the binary so far due to the following issue:

```
scons: *** 
[build/opt/mongo/db/s/namespace_metadata_change_notifications.o] Error 1
In file included from src/mongo/db/storage/recovery_unit.h:37:0,
    from src/mongo/db/operation_context.h:39,
    from src/mongo/client/read_preference.h:33,
    from src/mongo/s/client/shard.h:35,
    from src/mongo/s/catalog/sharding_catalog_client.h:41,
    from src/mongo/db/server_options.h:33,
    from src/mongo/base/secure_allocator.h:40,
    from src/mongo/db/auth/authorization_manager.h:35,
    from src/mongo/db/s/get_shard_version_command.cpp:35:
src/mongo/db/storage/snapshot.h: In member function 'std::__cxx11::string mongo::SnapshotId::toString() const':
src/mongo/db/storage/snapshot.h:61:16: error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
    return std::to_string(_id);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to build a development version from source. MongoDB 3.6 is out. You should build from one of the tags like r3.6.N on the branch v3.6. Also, can you provide the complete error message so we know what file and line?

Comment: I need to build from the source as I have other modules and storage engines that I need to add to the binary (e.g., https://github.com/pmem/pmse). Currently, I am trying to build the source and add the modules later after fixing the build issues.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your toolchain. On Ubuntu 18.04 using GCC 5.5, checked out to 3.5.13, I can certainly build `build/opt/mongo/db/s/namespace_metadata_change_notifications.o` with the command line `scons MONGO_VERSION=3.5.13 -j16 CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 build/opt/mongo/db/s/namespace_metadata_change_notifications.o`. I suggest you make a small toy program that includes `<string>` and ensure that you can compile and link a program which calls `std::to_string` on a `uint64_t`.